# Upload CSV file then Show Headings of columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$org_file_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($org_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $file_path = 'docs/';
            $rand = rand(111,999);          
        if($ext == 'csv')
        {
            if(file_exists($file_path))
                {
                     $file_path = 'docs/'.$org_file_name;
                }
            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$file_path))
                {
                    die ('<script> alert("file not uploaded successfully."); </script>');
                }           
        }
        else
        {
            die ('<script> alert("Uploaded only CSV files.");  </script>');
```

How Do I rename CSV file when uploading and insert into database with renam and after insert show csv column headings in buttons

Answer (score 0):

CSV headers (if present) are located right on the first line. So you can simply do:

```
$delimiter = ',';
$headers = fgetcsv(fopen($file_path, 'r'), $delimiter);

if (is_array($headers)) {
    foreach($headers as $header) {
         echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"$header\"
               value=\"$header\"/>'";
        }
    }
}
```

And to rename the file while moving, you should change the second parameter of move_uploaded_file() to the desired name. If you like, you can get a unique ID using sha1_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']). It will also avoid duplicated storage of identical files.

Comment: @Elixir Any output or log message?

Comment: File not uploaded successfully

Comment: @Elixir try using a full pathname istead of a relative one. Also try using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR if you are runing on both windows and linux. The problem can also be related to write permission on the target directory.